# How to store multiple input field data of a form into single table( model) in django

Tags: django-models, django-forms

I want to store multiple input data of a single form into one database(Model). After submitting the form the two input value will be added in one click means I want to add two category and two description with unique id of both in one click of submit button.

## Form.html File

```
 <form class="well form-horizontal" method="post" action="{% url 'add_category' %}">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                          <fieldset>
                             <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Category Name</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6 inputGroupContainer">
                                   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
<input id="fullName" name="cname" placeholder="Full Name" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                             <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Description</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6 inputGroupContainer">
                                   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
<input id="addressLine1" name="desc" placeholder="Address Line 1" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                                </div>
                             </div>


                             <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Category Name</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6 inputGroupContainer">
                                   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
<input id="fullName" name="cname1" placeholder="Full Name" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                             <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Description</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6 inputGroupContainer">
                                   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
<input id="addressLine1" name="desc1" placeholder="Address Line 1" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                             <button>Submit</button>
                          </fieldset>
                       </form>
```

## Model.Py File

```
class Category(models.Model): 
cname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
desc = models.CharField(max_length=50)

def __str__(self):
    return self.cname
```

## Views.Py File

```
def add_category(request):
print("from is submitted successfully!")
cname = request.POST.get(["cname","cname1"], False)
desc = request.POST.get(["desc","desc1"], False)

CategoryAdd = Category(cname = [cname,cname1], desc = [desc,desc1])
CategoryAdd.save()

return render(request,'addcategory.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use getlist for the operation and zip the cname and desc to get a tuple and convert zip to list and add to database. But to do so you need to give your html input elements name attribute must be same.

**HTML Form File**

```
<form>
  <input name="cname[]" placeholder="Full name"/>
  <input name="desc[]" placeholder="Description"/>
  <input name="cname[]" placeholder="Full name"/>
  <input name="desc[]" placeholder="Description"/>
</form>
```

**Model.Py File**

```
class Category(models.Model): 
  cname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  desc = models.CharField(max_length=50)

  def __str__(self):
      return self.cname
```

**Views.Py File**

```
def add_category(request):
  print("from is submitted successfully!")
  cname = request.POST.getlist("cname[]")
  desc = request.POST.getlist("desc[]")
  if len(cname)==len(desc) and cname and desc:
    mapped=zip(cname,desc)
    mapped=list(mapped)
    for ele in mapped:
      CategoryAdd,created = Category.objects.get_or_create(cname = ele[0],desc=ele[1])
  return render(request,'addcategory.html')
```

Comment: It's Working but the problem is both category and desc is added in one row.

Comment: I want that both the categories and desc should be added in model with different id's. @ Pavan Kumar TS

Comment: ill update the answer.  that would be simple. i added above answer based on your code.

Comment: I want that both the categories and desc should be added in model with different id's. @ Pavan Kumar TS

Comment: if the answer met what you expect close the question by accepting the answer